# C++ data race for memory mapped file

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-model

In C++, how are data races defined for memory from a memory-mapped file that is accessed by multiple threads from the same process?

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model), data races are defined with respect to *memory locations* and memory locations are defined as:

> an object of scalar type (arithmetic type, pointer type, enumeration type, std::nullptr_t)

or

> the largest contiguous sequence of bit fields of non-zero length

A memory mapped file is initialized as a `void*`. What are the memory locations of the memory pointed to by a `void*`? Does it depend on how accesses are type casted?

Comment: C++ has no file mapping. This is an OS feature. In Windows, you don't have any special thread safety.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Then maybe I should change the question to ask about accesses to memory allocated as a `void*` (i.e. with `::operator new(N)`). For the purpose of data races, how are memory locations defined in that case?

Comment: @DanielRicketts there is no thread safety on any non-atomic memory. You have to provide your own protection using existing synchronization primitives/APIs, like `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable`, etc.

Comment: I'm asking about the necessary granularity of this protection. The C++ memory model defines data races with respect to conflicting access to the same "memory location" (see the quoted definition in the question). But for a `void*`, it's not obvious what constitutes a memory location. Is each byte a separate memory location? If so concurrent accesses to different bytes would be safe.

Comment: You can't dereference a `void*`. You must needs access the underlying memory as some other type.

Comment: @Tandetnik I can cast it to a T* for some T. Does the definition of memory location depend on how I cast before accessing it? What happens if two different threads cast it to two different types? What if it points to a large memory region and different threads cast different offsets to different types?

Comment: The issue is object type used to read or write to memory, not the path used to obtain an address.

Comment: @curiousguy What do you mean by "the path used to obtain an address"?